# Wiki software that looks good via browser, iPhone and iPad?

Tags: iphone, wiki, mediawiki, wikipedia, ipad

I'm looking into new wiki software that looks good on browsers and kind of native on iPad and iPhone. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Confluence from [Atlassian](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) looks good (and more importantly works really well) on all popular browsers including Safari on iPhone and iPad.

NIC Labs have Mini Confluence Enterprise Engine (MCEE) native iOS app which integrates with a server plug-in that you need to buy separately.

There's also the Dash for Confluence iOS app from 3boxed Software, which is a simple but neat dashboard for viewing recent changes.